# Posting a large file via HTTP/REST in C# without loading file into memory

Tags: c#, large-files, multipart

I would like to upload a large file as a standard multipart post message.  All the C# examples I see however typically use byte arrays (which require the entire file be loaded into the contents of memory).  I can see that there is a StreamContent type but it isn't clear to me that embedding that in a multi part upload would stream the request with minimal memory impact.

Here's coding wise what I'm thinking.

```
using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage (HttpMethod.Post, uploadURL)) {
    MultipartFormDataContent multiPartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent ("----Abs23AawqrrqTbbSWpppo8--");
    StreamContent streamContent = new StreamContent (new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open));
    streamContent.Headers.Add ("Content-Type", "video/mov");
    streamContent.Headers.Add ("Content-Length", new FileInfo(path).Length.ToString() );
    multiPartContent.Add (streamContent, "bigMovie.mov", "bigMovie.mov");
    request.Content = multiPartContent;

    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync (request)) {
        // check status code
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way to handle a multi part upload for a large file that would be too big to load into memory?

Answer (score 0):

Doing it FTP way would be more efficient. FTP code also supports resume mode. And is more efficient protocol for file uplaod

Comment: Thank you but for a variety of permission related reasons I need to keep this a REST call.